# Is there an extension or a way to write an extension for firefox that allows a developer to refresh a page, but discard POST data?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, refresh, postdata

I'm a developer, and I spend much of my day refreshing the webapps I work on.  Occasionally, I'll encounter pages where POST data was submitted, and firefox will prompt me to Resend POST data or to Cancel.

Now, I know that I can just redirect a page to itself to get rid of this warning, but I still want to keep this warning for our users; I just want to be able to skip it while developing.  It's also not just on one page, but at many different points throughout the app, so it's not like I can just do if $debug==true then redirect or something like that.

Basically just a minor convenience issue, but when I encounter the message 50-100 times a day, it can get aggravating.  What I want to do is essentially have 3 options when refreshing: Resend POST data, cancel, or refresh without resending POST data

The third option would be equivalent to clicking "enter" in the address bar (which is what I end up having to do). The problem with clicking enter is that I often have to "hard refresh" using ctrl+shift+r, but if I do this with POST data I have to click cancel, then click enter on the address bar, then do a hard refresh after that.  I would instead like to press ctrl+shift+r, then continue hard refreshing the page without the POST data.

Does anyone know how to do this? Through an extension or otherwise? It's totally a minor issue, but it's something that constantly bothers me and I actually think it would be quite a useful option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look [here](http://groups.google.com/group/netscape.public.mozilla.wishlist/browse_thread/thread/38856f734ce6be58/b4890f521a072f91?#b4890f521a072f91).
There is a script that could be useful, but i didn't try it.

Comment: Thanks for the link - seems like I may be able to get it to work from that, though it requires recompiling ff, which might be more work than its worth.  I was hoping to pull it off with an extension, but so far haven't found any evidence that it's possible